# how to create a singular model and table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am an absolute beginner in laravel now I undertsand the concept that laravel creates singular model and plural table name e.g

```
php artisan make:model Admin -m

php artisan migrate
```

now this will create a model named **Admin** and a database named **admins** now logically I don't have a issue with that but it doesn't look clean if there is only one admin why need to have the table name as admins? Shouldn't it be **admin**? Is there any workaround for that or do I have to just stick with **admins**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the default name for the table, you can overwrite it in your model:

```
class Admin extends Model {
    protected $table = 'admin';
}
```

Comment: so now i can define my table name in db as admin?

Comment: yes, and eloquent will know where objects of class Admin are stored and load them correctly

Comment: perfect i was struggling with logic for some time . keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior. imagine the table as a bag, we have a bag of multiple users, articles or something else. but if you don't feel comfort with laravel standard, you can define your custom table name in your model.

```
class Admin extends Model {
protected $table = 'admin';
}
```